# Jfreechart - Refresh a chart according to changing data

Tags: java, refresh, jfreechart

I would like to know how to refresh a chart if we want to change "in live" some piece of data. I mean for instance, I have a chart with a TaskSeries which appears on 3 years and I would like to change 3 years by 5 years. I want the chart to change immediately.

Is there some kind of update chart or something like that ?

I know that you could say "get your TaskSeries, do your changes and it will be refreshed automatically" but my TaskSeries are generated and I cannot easily change these ones. That's why I would like to find a way to recalculate and to rebuild the whole chart.

Answer (score 7):

The `add()` method of [`TaskSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/gantt/TaskSeries.html) automatically sends a [`SeriesChangeEvent`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/SeriesChangeListener.html) to all registered listeners, e.g. `CategoryPlot`. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series/5048863#5048863), `DynamicTimeSeriesCollection` implements [`SeriesChangeEvent`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/SeriesChangeListener.html). In this case, the chart's `XYPlot` is a registered listener.

Comment: Is `XYPlot` registered as the listener which listens to `SeriesChangeEvent` by default when the `JFreeChart` is created by `ChartFactory` (that is to say, I don't need to register one by myself)? Your answer helped me twice in two days. Thanks!

Comment: Indirectly: [`AbstractSeriesDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/AbstractSeriesDataset.html) _forwards_ series changes to the plot, which (automatically) listens for `Dataset` changes.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue too with an XYPlot. I found a workaround by resetting the dataset:

```
chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(chart.getXYPlot().getDataset());
```

that's crazy but it works...

Note: `chart.setNotify(true)` seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue; I did it using this:

```
private void refreshChart() {
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.removeAll();
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.revalidate(); // This removes the old chart 
    aChart = createChart(); 
    aChart.removeLegend(); 
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(aChart); 
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.add(chartPanel); 
    jPanel_GraphicsTop.repaint(); // This method makes the new chart appear
}
```

Comment: you have any errors,but is a good solution
1.-refreshChart(
2.-aChart initialization

Answer (score 3):

```
// create a chart
ChartFrame mychartframe = new ChartFrame("my charts", chart);

// some other stuff ...

// somewhere else in a code far far away
mychartframe.getChartPanel().getChart().fireChartChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked with me was the following:

```
//reset with new dataset
chart().setDataset(dataset);
repaint the ChartPanel that contains the JFreeChart
chartPanel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an easy way to update a JFreeChart "live", since the data-structure of jfreechart is very incompatible to my data-structure. So I build a redraw()-Method of my own, that collects the data from my dataModel, build up a JFreeChart dataModel and set the chart new.

This gives the feeling of a "live" update, also it is very ugly.

Comment: I've found JFreeChart's approach very compatible with Swing's [separable model architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).