# Update normal distribution graph using JTextField in JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, jfreechart

I have a class that extends `JPanel` for `JFreeChart`. Inside of `setMean()`, I tried updating values of `dataset` or just the `Function2D`, but nothing changes on the graph even with `repaint()`.

```
    public class JFreeChartPanel extends JPanel {
        Function2D normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(0.0, 3.0);
        XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal, -5.0, 5.0, 100, "Normal");

        double mean = 0.0, std = 1.0;

        public double getMean() {
            return mean;
        }

        public void setMean(double mean) {
            this.mean = mean;
            normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(mean,std);
            dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal, -5.0, 5.0, 100, "Normal");
            repaint();
        }

        public double getStd() {
            return std;
        }

        public void setStd(double std) {
            this.std = std;
        }

        public JFreeChartPanel(){        

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Normal Distribution",
                "X", 
                "Y", 
                dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
            );


            final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(chartPanel);
        }
}
```

And this is executed everytime I change the value in my `JTextField`.

```
public void updateMean()
    {
        String meanS = mean.getText();
        double mean = 0.0;
        try{
            mean = Double.parseDouble(meanS);
            System.out.println("Mean: "+mean);
            jFreeChartPanel.setMean(mean);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Mean: incorrect input");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You change the values held by dataset but you never change the JFreeChart chart, and it's not going to magically change by itself. I don't use JFreeChart, but you're going to have to check the API to see if you either can call a method on the displayed chart or if you have to create a new one with the new data.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As far as I've read JFreeChart has a ton of listeners so any changes should automatically be reflected on the graph.

Comment: You don't understand how listeners work -- you have to set them up, wire them for them to function. Yes, you create a JFreeChart object using the dataset object, but again, simply changing dataset later will have no effect on the JFreeChart object. JFreeChart objects have a *model*, and if this model has listeners, and you make changes to the model using appropriate setter methods, methods that trip the listener, I could understand your expectations, but you don't. You're creating a completely new dataset object, and so there's no way that that could conceivably work as you assume it should.

Comment: For example, assume that the XYDataset object is wired into the JFreeChart object as its model (again, I don't use JFreeChart, and so this probably isn't so, but just assume that it is), then perhaps calling a method that changes its state might work, but again **you're creating a completely new XYDataset object**, so even if it were wired in as a listener, your new object can not cause any change in the JFreeChart object.

Comment: Found a duplicate on changing the chart series after data has been changed. Check out [TrashGod's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6206616/522444) in particular.

Comment: Also, please have a look at [these similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+jfreechart+change+dataset) that can be found on this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have went through all of those questions before asking here, I only create new objects because I went through documentation and there are no methods to implicitly change the data.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a DefaultIntervalXYDataset as your dataset as it allows for changing of the data with listeners.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is correct about _replacing_ the dataset, as suggested [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40167139/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, you could simply update the `XYDataset` used to create the `JFreeChart`, and the listening chart would update itself in response. As @Hovercraft [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163655/update-normal-distribution-graph-using-jtextfield-in-jfreechart/40167139#comment67596727_40163655), `repaint()` alone is not sufficient to tell the chart's plot that you have *replaced* the dataset. In the example below, I've refactored the dataset's initialization and passed it to `setDataset()` as a parameter.

```
public void setMean(double mean) {
    this.mean = mean;
    plot.setDataset(initDataset());
}
```

See the relevant [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#line.1371) to examine the event wiring. A `ChangeListener` added to a `JSpinner` may be easier to operate than a `JTextField`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.function.Function2D;
import org.jfree.data.function.NormalDistributionFunction2D;
import org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167139/230513
 */
public class TestDistribution {

    private static class JFreeChartPanel extends JPanel {

        private XYPlot plot;
        private double mean = 0.0, sigma = 1.0;
        XYDataset dataset = initDataset();

        private XYDataset initDataset() {
            Function2D normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(mean, sigma);
            XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal, -5.0, 5.0, 100, "Normal");
            return dataset;
        }

        ;
        public double getMean() {
            return mean;
        }

        public void setMean(double mean) {
            this.mean = mean;
            plot.setDataset(initDataset());
        }

        public double getStd() {
            return sigma;
        }

        public void setStd(double sigma) {
            this.sigma = sigma;
        }

        public JFreeChartPanel() {
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Normal Distribution", "X", "Y", dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false
            );
            plot = chart.getXYPlot();
            final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
            add(chartPanel);
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TestDistribution");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFreeChartPanel chartPanel = new JFreeChartPanel();
        f.add(chartPanel);
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setValue(chartPanel.mean);
        spinner.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
            JSpinner s = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
            Number n = (Number) s.getValue();
            chartPanel.setMean(n.doubleValue());
        });
        f.add(spinner, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TestDistribution()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: A related event chain is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6206616/230513).

Comment: If you don't mind I have one question is there an easy way to change tickUnits for my x-axis? Since it is using ValueAxis instead of NumberAxis I cannot access setTickUnit

Comment: `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()` uses `NumberAxis` internally, so you can cast; the new question is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40184461/230513).