# Is there a way to zoom a JFreechart chart to a value on X axis?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a bunch of charts and I'd like to zoom them all to highlight series at value x +- range based on an event not originating from within the charts.

If I'm reading it correctly all zooming chart methods such as `chart::zoomInDomain` take screen coordinates. So what I'm looking for is a way to either translate the x domain value to the screen coordinates in the chart or find an alternative way to zoom based on series values.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to adjust the relevant axis to flank the desired range. The exact formulation will depend on your data and goal. As a concrete example, starting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713994/230513), the following change to `createChart()` produces the chart below. It zooms to the value of the last day in the series, flanked by two days on the domain axis and a proportional amount on the range axis:

```
int n = dataset.getItemCount(0);
double dMin = dataset.getX(0, n - 3).doubleValue();
double dMax = dataset.getX(0, n - 1).doubleValue();
domain.setRange(dMin, 2 * dMax - dMin);
ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
double rMin = dataset.getY(0, n - 3).doubleValue();
double rMax = dataset.getY(0, n - 1).doubleValue();
range.setRange(rMin, 2 * rMax - rMin);
```

[image]

See also related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232680/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151032/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544007/230513).