# Re-calculating histogram on same frame and re-plot it using JFreechart

Tags: java, image, swing, histogram, jfreechart

In my main project I have a class which plots an Histogram in a frame using JFreeChart. From that frame I want to be able to replot the histogram with the number of bins the user wants.

In order to do that I've added a menu with a textfield and a button where the user can choose the number of bins. When he presses the button the whole frame get's repolted with the new number of bins.

My problem is that it just won't be ploted, the old frame gets disposed but instead of plotting something it just creates an empty frame. I don't get any error or exception so I've not idea where the problem can be. I suspect it has something to do with the JChart class or dataset but I can't find any information of what exactly isn't working.

I've tried to create a MCVE code from my code. From three tiff images called:

```
 "IMG_7911.CR2.R.TIFF", "IMG_7911.CR2.G.TIFF", "IMG_7911.CR2.B.TIFF"
```

(doesn't matter for the question how they look like, they all could be the same image) I create an histogram with a default bin size 2^16=16384, 16 bits. Then I want the user to be able to change the size from a menu. To do that I use the method "changeBinsSize" and "reDisplay":

```
 package mcve;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.DefaultDrawingSupplier;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYBarPainter;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.statistics.HistogramDataset;

public class HistogramRAW {

private int BINS;
private Raster raster;//Load image
private String filename;
private RenderedImage image;

private JFreeChart chart; //Create histogram
private ChartPanel panel;
private HistogramDataset dataset;
private XYBarRenderer renderer;
private JMenuBar menuBar; //Menubar
private JMenu options;

private JTextField numBINS;
private JFrame f; //Frame

public HistogramRAW(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
    this.BINS = 16384;
}

private void getImage(String filename) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(filename);
        final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
        raster=bi.getRaster();
        image=(RenderedImage)bi;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return;
    }
}

private ChartPanel createChartPanel() {
    // dataset
    dataset = new HistogramDataset();
    getImage(filename); //Put it here to get width and height from it
    final int w = image.getWidth();
    final int h = image.getHeight();

    double[] buffer = new double[w * h];

    //R
    buffer = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, buffer);
    dataset.addSeries("red", buffer, BINS);

    //G
    getImage(filename);
    buffer = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, buffer);
    dataset.addSeries("green", buffer, BINS);

    //B
    getImage(filename);
    buffer = raster.getSamples(0, 0, w, h, 0, buffer);
    dataset.addSeries("blue", buffer, BINS);

    //chart
    chart = ChartFactory.createHistogram("Histogram", "",
            "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    //Set colors
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    renderer = (XYBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardXYBarPainter());
    Paint[] paintArray = { // translucent red, green blue 
        new Color(0x800000ff, true),//blue
        new Color(0x8000ff00, true),//green1
        new Color(0x80ff0000, true)//red
    };
    plot.setDrawingSupplier(new DefaultDrawingSupplier(
            paintArray,
            DefaultDrawingSupplier.DEFAULT_FILL_PAINT_SEQUENCE,
            DefaultDrawingSupplier.DEFAULT_OUTLINE_PAINT_SEQUENCE,
            DefaultDrawingSupplier.DEFAULT_STROKE_SEQUENCE,
            DefaultDrawingSupplier.DEFAULT_OUTLINE_STROKE_SEQUENCE,
            DefaultDrawingSupplier.DEFAULT_SHAPE_SEQUENCE));

    //Create panel with chart
    panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);

    return panel;
}

private JMenuBar setMenuBar() {
    menuBar = new JMenuBar(); //Create Menubar

    options = new JMenu("Options"); //  menu.
    options.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    menuBar.add(options);

    JPanel binsPanel = new JPanel(); //Change BINS size button
    numBINS = new JTextField("" + BINS);
    binsPanel.add(numBINS);
    JButton binsButton = new JButton("changeBins");
    binsButton.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    binsPanel.add(binsButton);
    options.add(binsPanel);

    return menuBar;
}

public void display() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    f = new JFrame("Histogram");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(createChartPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setJMenuBar(setMenuBar());
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void reDisplay() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    f.add(createChartPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setJMenuBar(setMenuBar());
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);

}

public void changeBinsSize() {
    try {
        BINS = Integer.parseInt(numBINS.getText());
        f.removeAll();
        f.dispose();
        System.out.println("" + BINS);
        reDisplay();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        HistogramRAW hist = new HistogramRAW("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/245px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png");
        hist.display();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("changeBins")) {
            changeBinsSize();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Update**: I modified the code to download a random photo instead of the tiff and all channels are the same photo.

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?, I've been for hours trying to see what's wrong but I can't find anything.

Comment: Don't remove the view; update the dataset. In your [mcve], access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I just updated the MCVE, I think now should work properly by accessing and URL as your first answer suggests. 
--- I also tried to update the dataset but I don't see any way of deleting series, and for my project it's important that the RGB series have the same index, as I have some buttons which act on them. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/HistogramDataset.html

Comment: Ah, I see your point; more below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your present implementation of `changeBinsSize()` tries to *replace* the view component. Instead, update the model and the listening view will update itself.

> I tried to update the dataset, but I don't see any way of deleting series.

The `addSeries()` method of [`HistogramDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/HistogramDataset.html) adjusts the dataset's internal state as a function of the number of bins. As a result, you'll need to recreate the `dataset` from the original image samples, passing the new bin count as a parameter to `addSeries()`. Use the `setDataset()` method of [`XYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) to replace the dataset, which will notify the listening plot to update itself. A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167139/230513).

Comment: Thank's a lot, that was it. I've to get used to look at that XYPlot class. It's quite strange to have to work with it instead of directly over the data objects.