# Use XYSplineRenderer instead of line chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using `createLineChart` to create a graph. This appears as any line graph.

What I would like is to apply `XYSplineRenderer` so that the lines are curved. Is it possible?

Here's the code. It's just a simple `CreateLineChart`, so I was wondering if it's possible to apply that Renderer, since one of the values is `String` and is a range of values.

[image]

```
public class Intento1 extends JFrame {

    JFreeChart Grafica;
    JFreeChart Grafica2;
    JFreeChart Grafica3;
    DefaultCategoryDataset Datos = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    DefaultCategoryDataset Datos2 = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    //XYDataset Datos2 = new XYDataset();

    //XYSplineRenderer render = new XYSplineRenderer();

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intento1 frame = new Intento1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Intento1() {

        Datos.addValue(1, "Frecuencia", "Menos de 46");
        Datos.addValue(1, "Frecuencia", "46-55");
        Datos.addValue(3, "Frecuencia", "56-65");
        Datos.addValue(7, "Frecuencia", "66-75");
        Datos.addValue(11, "Frecuencia", "76-85");
        Datos.addValue(21, "Frecuencia", "86-95");
        Datos.addValue(28, "Frecuencia", "96-105");
        Datos.addValue(16, "Frecuencia", "106-115");
        Datos.addValue(22, "Frecuencia", "116-125");
        Datos.addValue(7, "Frecuencia", "126-135");
        Datos.addValue(1, "Frecuencia", "136-145");
        Datos.addValue(2, "Frecuencia", "146 o Mas");

        Datos2.addValue(0.008, "Frecuencia Relativa", "Menos de 46");
        Datos2.addValue(0.008, "Frecuencia Relativa", "46-55");
        Datos2.addValue(0.025, "Frecuencia Relativa", "56-65");
        Datos2.addValue(0.058, "Frecuencia Relativa", "66-75");
        Datos2.addValue(0.092, "Frecuencia Relativa", "76-85");
        Datos2.addValue(0.175, "Frecuencia Relativa", "86-95");
        Datos2.addValue(0.234, "Frecuencia Relativa", "96-105");
        Datos2.addValue(0.134, "Frecuencia Relativa", "106-115");
        Datos2.addValue(0.183, "Frecuencia Relativa", "116-125");
        Datos2.addValue(0.058, "Frecuencia Relativa", "126-135");
        Datos2.addValue(0.008, "Frecuencia Relativa", "136-145");
        Datos2.addValue(0.017, "Frecuencia Relativa", "146 o Mas");
        //Grafica.getXYPlot().setRenderer(render);

        Grafica = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Variable continua"
                    , "Produccion", "Frecuencia", Datos, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                    true,true,false);
        Grafica2 = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Variable continua"
                , "Produccion", "Frecuencia", Datos2, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,true,false);
        Grafica3=ChartFactory.createLineChart ("Variablew", "Produccion", "Frecuencia", Datos2, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);

        CategoryPlot plot = Grafica.getCategoryPlot();
        //XYPlot awa =  Grafica.getPlot();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnGraficar = new JButton("Graficar");
        btnGraficar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                ChartPanel Panel = new ChartPanel(Grafica);
                    JFrame Ventana = new JFrame("JFreeChart");
                    Ventana.getContentPane().add(Panel);
                    Ventana.pack();
                    Ventana.setVisible(true);
                    Ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
        btnGraficar.setBounds(160, 36, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGraficar);

        JButton btnGraficarRelativas = new JButton("Graficar Relativas");
        btnGraficarRelativas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ChartPanel Panel = new ChartPanel(Grafica2);
                JFrame Ventana = new JFrame("JFreeChart");
                Ventana.getContentPane().add(Panel);
                Ventana.pack();
                Ventana.setVisible(true);
                Ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
        btnGraficarRelativas.setBounds(160, 95, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGraficarRelativas);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already added the code, what it generates is a graph with peaks and I would like to give it curves, read to see if something helps me.

Answer (score 2):

No existing `ChartFactory` uses `XYSplineRenderer`, and I was unsure about your existing datasets. I started from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790187/230513) and sampled a normal distribution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167139/230513) to get the original example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55418498/1). You may have to adjust the `precision` to suit your data. You can alter the domain axis labels as needed using any of the methods suggested in [*How can I change the* `tickLabel` *on a `NumberAxis`…?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2365657/230513).

> My data set uses `int String String`

Reading more closely, the first `String` is the series key, which I have labeled `"Frequency"`; the second appears to be a numeric range. This new example illustrates using a higher precision and a `SymbolAxis`, which should work better for your dozen or so ranges.

Updated example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SymbolAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYSplineRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418498/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790187/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167139/230513
 */
public class SplineTest {

    public static final String Title = "Spline Test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SplineTest()::display);
    }

    private void display() {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Frequency");
        series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 1);
        series.add(2, 3);
        series.add(3, 7);
        series.add(4, 11);
        series.add(5, 21);
        series.add(6, 28);
        series.add(7, 16);
        series.add(8, 22);
        series.add(9, 7);
        series.add(10, 1);
        series.add(11, 2);
        XYDataset dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        String[] labels = new String[series.getItemCount()];
        labels[0] = "<46";
        labels[1] = "46-55";
        labels[2] = "56-65";
        labels[3] = "66-75";
        labels[4] = "76-85";
        labels[5] = "86-95";
        labels[6] = "96-105";
        labels[7] = "106-115";
        labels[8] = "116-125";
        labels[9] = "126-135";
        labels[10] = "136-145";
        labels[11] = ">146";
        NumberAxis domain = new SymbolAxis("X", labels);
        NumberAxis range = new NumberAxis("Y");
        XYSplineRenderer r = new XYSplineRenderer(8);
        XYPlot xyplot = new XYPlot(dataset, domain, range, r);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(xyplot);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(Title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(chartPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to see what works.
In my data set use int string string.