# Add multi series spline chart in PDF using itext pdf

Tags: itext, jfreechart, canvasjs

I don't have any clue how to draw multi series spline chart using [`iText`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/info). I have done it on JSP page using `canvas.js`. I can't find any solution for [`iText`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/info). If any one has any idea or source to do it please let me know.

Comment: Start with one spline chart like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418498/230513).